# Prop in stateless component fat arrow function cannot be validated with eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Foo = (props) => {
  const myFunc = () => (
    <div>
      { props.bar }
    </div>
  );

  return myFunc();
};

Foo.propTypes = {
  bar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Foo;
```

Eslint tells me:

> 'bar' is missing in props validation

It seems as though when the fat arrow returns JSX, eslint fails.

I can get around this by assigning `bar` to `this`:

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  this.bar = props.bar; //eslint sees this properly

  const myFunc = () => (
    <div>
      { this.bar }
    </div>
  );
```

Is this the best way to go about this? Why is this happening?

**.eslintrc**

// .eslint.json

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2016,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
     "es6": true,
     "jest": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "import",
    "jsx-a11y"
  ],
  "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
        "func-names": 0,
        "strict": 0,
        "quotes": [1, "single"],
        "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
        "react/prefer-es6-class": 0,
        "babel/generator-star-spacing": 0,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
        "no-named-as-default": 0,
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `.eslintrc` please?

Comment: Just for clarification, "'bar' is missing in props validation" sounds like that's an error related to the propTypes declaration. Does eslint error even if you haven't instantiated <Foo bar="test" /> anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered a strange behaviour. The only difference is in the return statement:
[image]
[image]

Now also the `bar` in `propTypes` is uncommented:
[image]
[image]

*PS: You could also use destructuring to get around the props validation `Foo = ({ bar }) => ...` instead of having to assign it `const bar = props.bar`.*

I think the problem is because the `myFunc` looks like a functional component and that eslint is picking it up wrongly.
[image]

Also, this is rather funny, if you simply rename the `props` to anything else, eslint goes silent :)
[image]

//edit
Seems like my reasoning was somewhat correct https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2135#issuecomment-455034857

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you do it this way?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Foo = (props) => {
  const myFunc = (bar) => (
    <div>
      { bar }
    </div>
  );

  // access bar here.
  return myFunc(props.bar);
};

Foo.propTypes = {
  bar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine what's happening is `myFunc` is seen as another stateless component. Just eyeballing your code, it looks valid, but eslint likely is seeing `myFunc` as needing its own `propTypes`, even though the `props` you are accessing is in the same scope. You could verify this by doing something like:

```
const myFunc = (props) => (
  <div>
    { props.bar }
  </div>
);
myFunc.propTypes = {
  bar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

return myFunc({ bar: props.bar });
```

But for practical advice on this, I would suggest just returning

```
<div>
  { props.bar }
</div>
```

from your `Foo` instead of creating a closure inside it.